# jQuery click function by class not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have two lists with different classes,

```
<li><a href='#' class="cls1" name="X">blah</a></li> <!-- Click to load a cls2 item -->
<li><a href='#' class="cls1" name="Y">blah</a></li>

<li><a href='#' class="cls2" name="A">blah</a></li>
<li><a href='#' class="cls2" name="B">blah</a></li>
```

I have this script to handle click function.

```
$(function(){
$('.cls1').click(function(e){
    alert('cls1 clicked');
    e.preventDefault();
    ... //ajax call to load cls2 items
    });
$('.cls2').click(function(e){
    alert('cls2 clicked');
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
    });
)};
```

**Important** The cls2 class items are loaded by an ajax function called in cls1 click function

The cls1 items click function works fine, but when i click any cls2 item, nothing happens.

Is there any problem by adding it after the whole page loads? (by ajax call)

Another issue I notted is that if i refresh the page, and i change the cls1 class to cls2 in the code (using chrome console) the css changes correctly but it still doing the cls1 click function. Why???

Any Idea? I have tried to change the click function order, change the class names, even with another jquery library... (I am using v1.11.1)

Issue example here: http://jsfiddle.net/f7o5y3ek/

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: I think it's perfect answer on this question

Comment: this is an example of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/f7o5y3ek/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the cls2 click handler to the ajax success part or try with this:

```
$(document).on('click, '.cls2', function(e){
    alert('cls2 clicked');
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
    });
)};
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, your issue is you're adding event listeners to elements that don't exist yet. You have to add the `.cls2` listeners after those elements are created by your ajax call.

Something like this (converted form Coffeescript, sorry):

```
$.ajax("path/to/call", {
  success: (function(_this) {
    return function() {
      return _this.addItems;
    };
  })(this)
});

({
  addItems: function() {
    // add new items & listeners here
  }
});
```

Alternately, and better I think, is to use event delegation, like this:

```
$( "parent_selector" ).on( "click", ".cls2", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log( "clicked!" );
});
```

Comment: if I add an "invisible" cls2 item at the beginning, and then add the others by ajax, will it work?

Comment: Nope. Check out the event delegation solution at the end, for a more robust solution.